# Is it ok to replace clients username id with their email?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to replace username id with their email. Is it ok to do that?

For example in MySQL table:

```
client_id
som665
som881
som876
som887
```

I want to replace them with emails for future clients e.g.:

```
client_id
som665
som881
som876
som887
xyz123@gmail.com
xyy333@gmail.com
xcv5557@yahoo.com
```

Question-
Does replacing `client_id` like `som881` with email make my software (or query) slow? When I use below query on emails instead of small id's like `som881`?

```
$sel_service = "select * from all_services where client_id='$client_id' order by sub_cat_name"
```

Right now my clients login with client id like `som881` which is difficult for them to remember compared to an email address. I'm also unable to provide "forgot your password?" functionality.

Comment: and if some one changes therir email address? most systems would use both.

Comment: Even if you have a few thousand user accounts, changing the query to look for emails (or `WHERE client=? or email=?` - why not both?) wouldn't have a significant speediness impact.

Comment: That query opens your to SQL injections hopefully that is just an example and you escape `$client_id` or use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well this is a very good use of emails because mail servers of companies doesnt allow clients to have same username so you dont even need to set a primary key constraint on this id field .
you know nowadays databases finds the best algorithm to search between records by their Artificial Intelligence so the only thing you should worry about is :
is it worth to provide your clients comfortability at the expense of complexity !?

if yes in my opinion there wont be any problem if the server responds a little slower

---

i suggest you to use at least one security server service layer using precreated classes between client and database server that accepts clients connections and created one way virtual connections to database server for searching login information instead of explicit SQL command to provide a higher level of security and rejecting SQLInjection

Comment: do I prefer an email addr when I login to FB, paypal, etc, You bet. Cause they have huge teams of programmers that nail that stuff down.

Comment: @Drew 50% agreed but you see there must be an email confirmation email to submit a username and i think companies wont delete accounts physically there might be just a logic delete beside that  many other sites uses emails as clients username . in this case that he represented its data you see IDs are something like auto-generated usernames .
substitution in this case i dont think it makes a sense . but everythings depends on what is he doing with that server . seems he just wanted to know about server responds

Comment: I can no longer access certain logins to email, cuz I released them, now someone else has them (as in my mehdi@outlook.com reference). Now someone else gets it. The OP or anyone better have all that ironed out before email addresses are used for logins. I don't worry about those things because I can change my login credentials because THEY worried about it with SMS and fallback email address for recovery. So it is not a simple, hey, you are fine, good to go.

Comment: @Mehdi  everything is working fine by replacing id's with email, Only speed is the issue. In our software we have to display and insert(using excel upload) thousands of rows related to the client_id , Does using email instead of small id's  in Mysql queries - SELECT and INSERT  make my software slow?

Comment: @Drew thanks for your suggestion but every company is using email address as a username these days , eg every big and small online payment companies like ebay , amazon etc are using same method.

Comment: so you are suggesting, then, that when you login, that your actual transactions in tables are being saved as primary key  `jonathanhumphries@westdsl.newyork.comcastbusiness.net` ?  And there could be tens of thousands of transactions for you. And when you become `john123@aol.com` they innodb lock all the rows and change all of them ?

Comment: @Drew i didnt heard something like this for companies like yahoo , google and etc . please tell the company name so we wont signup there lol

Comment: @Metu007 i think yes but its just a bit even cant be calculated for a single connection

Comment: now go into your profile, change your nickname to, well, I have some suggestions, but you do it. Let's say Snoopy. What happens **Mehdi**? What happens is that you are still user 5217080.

Comment: and we can always get to you by http://stackoverflow.com/users/5217080  Because some people know how to design systems

Comment: @Metu007 you know i think Drew is right
using emails is a good idea but it wont be that simple
maybe have emails as an additional information for help in login might be helpfull if you want to step in to this login procedure so quick

Comment: I certainly can complicate things. There are 2 separate issues (at least) at play here. **1)** I think email addresses are great for logging in. I probably won't forget my username, and if I do, there can be well laid-out mechanisms for account recovery to fallback email addresses or SMS text messages **2)** Data in tables need to have as thin as possible primary keys to make joins fly (like on ints), and they need to be not changed, like Mehdi is 5217080 and I am 1816093. We can be whatever we want when we login, but all our data is iced in stone with quick joins on thin id's.

Comment: Never change PK's in millions of rows because someone wants to be Robert as they are sick of being Bob.

Comment: @Metu007 do you use any encryption ?

Comment: No i dont use any encryption

Comment: @Metu007 well seems records in your database are pure rare
how much security is important in your accounting solution ?
if less than servers speed dont wory about the substitution you made

Answer (score 0):

The longer the string the more time it will take to query the users because it will match more number of chars,

so if you want to make it with the email ( and yes it easier for the user ).
you have to make this field as unique index .
in this way mysql will index the emails and it will find the user record without scaning the entire table.

but the drawback of it that it will take more space for the index. but it will be very fast

and if the user will have more than record( have more than service), then you have to make it just index not unique

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in our system email(client_id) is related to every thing, not just for Login purpose, we have to display or paginate(using SELECT query) and insert(using mysql INSERT) thousands of rows , and every row contain that email(client_id) in our Mysql database.
My question is- Does using user123@example.com instead of xyz111 make our system slow .

Comment: yes ok, this way if you want it to be fast you have to make it as index at all tables which you are using it or it will be slow, and it will take more size for the index for each table but it will keep the speed good.

and i also suggest - if possible at your application - to use email at during the login time only but not as the id and then map between it and int id with the way @vhu mentioned as the size and index of the int id is less than the string id

Answer (score 0):

Overall your question is very broad without details of the application you are working on.

I'd say that in general, yes, it'd be good idea to allow users to login using the email address. If are mainly concerned about the slowdown this shouldn't be an issue as this should only impact login which doesn't happen all that often.

From design perspective you probably should have two identifiers for the user:

1. User visible token. This can be username chosen by the user (user123) or email address (user123@example.com). This token is only used when user logs in to the application. You may even go as far as having two different columns to store the username and email address. In this case your login part needs to match the username against both database columns.
2. Internal identifier used in application. `id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` column might do well, depending on your intended scale. This is what your application should use internally. You don't even need to show this to the user.

This would allow users to change their email address without having to recreate their account.

**EDIT:** based on your comment, you use `client_id` as both index value to reference data between the tables in the database *and* as a username user logs in with. My suggestion is to normalize the data as listed above.

If you don't normalize the data, you may end up with over-sized index columns in several tables. To store email address you need to use string (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR`) column with significant length. With normalized data you just need `INT`/`BIGINT` in each table. In this scenario allowing users to use email address may slow down as it may require `client_id` column to be resized.

Comment: thanks for your answer, in our system email(client_id) is related to every thing, not just for Login purpose, we have to display or paginate(using SELECT query) and insert(using mysql INSERT) thousands of rows , and every row contain that email(client_id) in our Mysql database.

Comment: My question is- Does using user123@example.com instead of xyz111 make our system slow .